# tmux spaces between window panels

Tags: arch-linux, tmux

How to disable these spaces between window panels in tmux? 
[image]

**~/.tmux.conf**

```
#background color
set -g status-bg colour63
#window settings
set -g window-status-current-style fg=black,bg=colour75
set -g window-status-style bg=colour68
setw -g window-status-format ' #I [#W] '
setw -g window-status-current-format ' #I [#W] '

#status lines in panel on left and right
set -g status-right '#[bg=colour75][#S]'
set -g status-left ''
#separator lines
set-option -g pane-active-border-style "bg=default"
set-option -ag pane-active-border-style "fg=colour63"
```

Comment: Do you have a tmux config file - either `/etc/tmux.conf` or `~/.tmux.conf` and if so what is in it?

Comment: @icarus I have added ~/.tmux.conf to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set window-status-separator.

Answer (score 2):

In the `~/.tmux.conf` file there are

```
setw -g window-status-format ' #I [#W] '
setw -g window-status-current-format ' #I [#W] '
```

lines, which describe the format used for the windows in the status line. The `#I` is the index number, and the `#W` is the window name.

There are extra spaces at the start and end of these strings, which gives the spaces that are unwanted.

As an experiment you can change this inside a tmux session by running

```
 tmux setw -g window-status-format '#I [#W]'
```

Edit: @NicholasMarriott has the correct answer, rather than this one.